# how to fix Undefined variable: users in laravel view

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, php-7

I'm using this package [spatie-laravel-permission](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-permission)

to add roles and permissions to my website.

in my admin dashboard, I fetched all users and set a delete method.

```
public function user_destroy ($id){

        $user_delete= User::findOrFail($id);

            $user_delete->removeRole($user_delete->getRoleNames());
            $user_delete->delete();


        return view('admin.users.index')->with('success','User is deleted');
    }
```

so using the code above does not remove the user and his role.

I get this error :

```
Return value of App\User::getStoredRole() must implement interface Spatie\Permission\Contracts\Role, instance of Illuminate\Support\Collection returned
```

i tried to use PHP detach() :

```
 $user_delete->roles()->detach();
```

It is actually working but I get this error :

```
Undefined variable: users (View: resources\views\admin\users\index.blade.php)
```

The PHP $users are defined in the index view like this :

```
public function mainUsers(){

       $users = User::latest()->paginate(5);
       return view('admin.users.index',compact('users'));

   }
```

I don't know what is the problem when I use `PHP detach()` the $users are defined and I get all the users on my index.

Any idea of how I can solve this problem:?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it turns out that I'm returning a view which expecting a `$users` instead of redirecting to the index of users.

changing from :

```
     return view('admin.users.index')->with('success','User is deleted');
```

TO :

```
return redirect()->route('users.index')->with('success','User is deleted');
```

fixed the whole darn problem